# Laravel Query Exception

Tags: laravel, exception

When I tried to delete a row which ID related to another table
I got this error

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row`

How can I show this error.
I've tried with try catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e)
But it not work
Can I have your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with PDO exception

```
    try {
            $this->model->create($data);

        } catch (Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
            dd($e);

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            dd($e);
        }
```

Comment: I use your code with `try { $brand->delete() }`..... But I still got it error. I think I wrong somewhere so It can not catch.

Comment: @SangTrần di you try both query and pdo exception?